# MAUI redirect from page OnAppearing() event (ShellContent)

Tags: .net, maui

In a page's OnAppearing() event handler I want to redirect to another page if a certain condition is met. However, I get an error saying that navigation actions are still pending.

I couldn't find an event on the ShellContent item, like an OnClick() event to intercept either.

Comment: Can you post the snippet of your code where you're getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `async` method like this.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//LoginPage");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, it works, thanks!

Although having to await a delay seems like a pretty nasty workaround. Hopefully this gets fixed soon.